# create a private git repo in bitbucket?

Tags: javascript, git, bitbucket

first i create an account in bitbucket, then i create a shh private key in puttykeygen, i save the private key "bitbucket.ppk", then i copy the text from public key and i paste in my account in bitbucket, in SSH KEY section. before that, i make a repo in bitbucket called ATOMICO.

this is my question

why can i clone the repo without the private key??

how can i restrict that function???, because everybody can clone my repo and push changes without the private key... i try to clone my repo in other computer and i could push changes

the repo is git clone https://andrescabana86@bitbucket.org/andrescabana86/atomico.git

try to push changes if you can do that tell me

EDIT 2

im following these lines to push

```
$ git commit -m "cambios from me"
[master 36b6908] cambios from me
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 cambios de mi.txt
wirelan@WIRELAN-HM /E/UPW/webs/atomico (master)
$ git push -u origin --all
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 246 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: bb/acl: andrescabana86 is allowed. accepted payload.
To https://andrescabana86@bitbucket.org/andrescabana86/atomico.git
   eae426a..36b6908  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

tnx all

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have the same private key on the other computer? Here is what I got:  
`git clone https://andrescabana86@bitbucket.org/andrescabana86/atomico.git
Cloning into 'atomico'...
Password for 'https://andrescabana86@bitbucket.org': 
fatal: Authentication failed
`
  
So to me it appears to private as you intended for it to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
$  git clone https://andrescabana86@bitbucket.org/andrescabana86/atomico.git
=> Password for 'https://andrescabana86@bitbucket.org':
```

Your repository seems pretty private to me. You can clone it to your local machine *because* of the public/private key pairs that you've set up.

Comment: i clone the repo from other notebook, i try twice and i could push changes from two differents notebooks beside mine, , but tnx for your time and your consideration

Comment: Do you have the same private key on your other notebook? Or do you have your other notebook's public key on bitbucket also?

Comment: no, i create the private key in one notebook, i clone the repo from two notebooks that didnt have the private key

Comment: Double check that you only have the one public key in your ssh keys on bitbucket. If you only have the one public key on bitbucket and it corresponds to the private key on only one notebook then I have no idea.